# jQuery irregularity in Backbone view.render()

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, backbone-views

Under what circumstances would this happen:

```
 this.$el.append(ret);  //doesn't work

 $(this.el).append(ret); //works
```

I instantiate the view like this:

```
new allViews.UserProfile({el: '#main-content-id',collection: collections.users}),
```

so maybe I should be using $el instead of el to instantiate the view. Why does Backbone make that distinction, this is crazy.

I should have mentioned this before, but here is one non-standard thing I am doing. One thing that irritates me is that Backbone doesn't allow for 'defaults' in views. This is wrong - for example - you may want a default collection for a view, but if you pass in a collection in the constructor then that overrides the default. Pretty reasonable. So basically I tried to manually copy what's in Backbone.Model for Backbone.View.

So here is the View, in its entiriety for your pleasure:

```
    var UserProfileView = Backbone.View.extend({

            defaults: function () {
                return {
                    model: null,
                    collection: collections.users,
                    childViews: {}
                }
            },
            events: {

            },

            constructor: function () {
                this.givenName = '@UserProfileView';
                Backbone.View.apply(this, arguments);
            },

            initialize: function (opts) {

                Backbone.setViewProps(this, opts); //has side effects

            },
            render: function () {

               var data = this.collection.models;

               renderThis.bind(this)(UserProfileView.template);


                function renderThis($template) {
                    var ret = EJS.render($template, {
                        users: data
                    });

                    //this.$el.append(ret);

                    $(this.el).append(ret);

                }
                return this;
            }
        },
        { //class properties
            template: template
        }
    );
```

and here is the non-standard function that every view is run through, and this function is called in the view.initialize() function:

```
  Backbone.setViewProps = function(view,options){

            var opts = options || {};

            var temp = _.defaults({}, opts, _.result(view, 'defaults'));

            for(var prop in temp){
                if(temp.hasOwnProperty(prop) && prop !== undefined){
                    if(temp[prop]!==undefined){
                        view[prop] = temp[prop];
                    }
                }
            }
        };
```

so what I think is happening is that when I pass el as an option it gets pre-maturely tacked on to the view and then Backbone prematurely calls

```
 this.setElement(_.result(this, 'el'));
```

from inside this in the Backbone source

```
 _ensureElement: function() {
      if (!this.el) {
        var attrs = _.extend({}, _.result(this, 'attributes'));
        if (this.id) attrs.id = _.result(this, 'id');
        if (this.className) attrs['class'] = _.result(this, 'className');
        this.setElement(this._createElement(_.result(this, 'tagName')));
        this._setAttributes(attrs);
      } else {
        this.setElement(_.result(this, 'el'));
      }
    },
```

which in turn calls

```
 _setElement: function(el) {
      this.$el = el instanceof Backbone.$ ? el : Backbone.$(el);
      this.el = this.$el[0];
    },
```

Comment: Backbone does not make that distinction. `this.$el` and `$(this.el)` should be identical.

Comment: @muistooshort no, the above is the only place where I am setting the el. I debugged and in the Backbone source this line is executed: this.setElement(_.result(this, 'el')); which means that the el was defined when the view constructor was called. So it looks like everything is totally standard. However there is one non-standard thing that I am doing and I added that to the question. Maybe someone can help figure out how that causes this issue, because it has to be that.

Comment: I think the best way someone could help me is to help create a better way to have default attributes for a View because clearly the way I am doing it is messing stuff up. There seems to be attributes for Backbone.View but I doubt the attributes behave the same way as the attributes for Backbone.Model...

Answer (score 1):

I'm totally not sure about what you are trying to do, but I'll just answer on your question in the comments:

> I think the best way someone could help me is to help create a better
>   way to have default attributes for a View

and

> One thing that irritates me is that Backbone doesn't allow for
>   'defaults' in views.

I don't see what stops you from defining defaults on your backbone view and allowing override using the options parameter that can be passed in:

```
var View = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function(options){
        this.defaults = { 
            name: "default", 
            color: "blue" 
        }; 

        this.attributes= $.extend({}, this.defaults, options); 
    }
})
```

You can override these attributes by passing them in when instantiating the view:

```
var view = new View({name: "Alex", color: "red"});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/C9wew/7299/

Comment: thanks, I am going to try to put defaults outside the initialize function for now, I think I was just doing it wrong. What I wanted to do is only override the defaults if a null or defined value was passed in, but not an undefined value. I am not sure if Underscore has such a function.

Comment: Underscore has a convenience method `_.isUndefined`.

Comment: are you certain that this line is correct  this.attributes= $.extend({}, this.defaults, options); , I would guess that the leftmost arguments override the ones to the right...so options should be to the left of defaults?

Comment: I'm sure it's correct; this is also how jquery plugins are built. Check: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/

Comment: i think underscore extend is the opposite of this in terms of arguments

Answer (score 1):

Your `setViewProps` function is probably the source of your problems. You're passing an `el` into your view when you create it. That means that the `options` that `setViewProps` sees will have an `el` in it, in particular, that `el` will be the string `'#main-content-id'`. Then your `setViewProps` will effectively say:

```
view.el = '#main-content-id`;
```

and everything falls apart. The [`el` property](http://backbonejs.org/#View-el) is a DOM node:

> **el** `view.el`
>
> All views have a DOM element at all times (the **el** property), [...].
>
> `this.el` can be resolved from a DOM selector string or an Element; [...].

The `el` can be *resolved* from a selector string but it should still be a DOM element. The `el` *option* can be a selector string but the `el` *property* should be a DOM element.

Note that the docs say that:

> All views have a DOM element at all times

so the conversion of the string `el` option passed to the view to the DOM element `el` property happens *before* `initialize` gets called. That means that your `setViewProps` is inadvertently overwriting the `el` property (a DOM element) with a string.

You shouldn't blindly assume that all the options passed to your view should be copied to view properties: some properties (such as `el`) need special treatment, some shouldn't be copied at all (such as an accidental `render` option). If you really must do this sort of thing then you should whitelist the properties that you copy:

```
var temp = _.result(view, 'defaults') || { };
for(var prop in temp) {
    //...
}
```

You could also attach this function directly to Backbone.View's prototype:

```
Backbone.View.prototype.setViewProps = function(options) {
    // use `this` instead of `view` in here
};
```

and then say:

```
this.setViewProps(options);
```

inside your `initialize`.

---

There are some other strange things going on here.

Don't do this:

```
constructor: function () {
    this.givenName = '@UserProfileView';
    Backbone.View.apply(this, arguments);
}
```

The `constructor` is AFAIK more about supporting CoffeeScript's `class V extends Backbone.View` than anything you should be doing. The "real" constructor function in Backbone is `initialize` and Backbone will call that at the appropriate times. If you want a `givenName` property then leave it on the prototype with everything else that isn't instance-specific:

```
var UserProfileView = Backbone.View.extend({
    givenName: '@UserProfileView',
    //...
});
```

or, if you need [`hasOwnProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) to say `true` for some reason, assign it in `initialize`:

```
initialize: function() {
    this.givenName = '@UserProfileView';
    //...
}
```

Using [`for...in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) on a view instance should be pretty rare so I'd leave it on the prototype.

Similarly, attaching `template` to the "class" is a bit odd, you should just leave it on the prototype and refer to it as `this.template`.

Your `render` is a bit odd:

```
render: function () {
    var data = this.collection.models;
    renderThis.bind(this)(UserProfileView.template);
    function renderThis($template) {
        var ret = EJS.render($template, {
            users: data
        });
        $(this.el).append(ret);
    }
    return this;
}
```

1. You generally don't mess with a collection's `models` property. You usually use one of the [mixed in Underscore functions](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-Underscore-Methods) to iterate over the collection (e.g. `this.collection.each(function(model) { ... })`) or serialize it to raw data using [`toJSON`](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-toJSON). Using `toJSON` is more common with views so that your templates don't accidentally change anything.
2. `UserProfileView.template` is covered above.
3. `$(this.el)` is covered way up above.
4. I don't understand why you have a `renderThis` inner function, why not do that right inside `render`?

Something like this would be more idiomatic:

```
render: function() {
    var html = EJS.render(this.template, {
        data: this.collection.toJSON()
    });
    this.$el.html(html);
    return this;
}
```

You'd need to modify the template to work with an array of plain objects rather than an array of models of course.

Comment: thanks Mu I think this is pretty much it, let me investigate and get back to you with verification

Comment: Don't worry if prototypical inheritance takes a bit of getting used to when you're coming from an environment with separate classes.

Comment: well one thing I can't tell for sure is if I need to pass into a view constructor: {el: $('#elem')} or just {el: '#elem'}...

Comment: Either of those should work. I prefer not to pass `el` at all though, I have fewer problems if the view creates and owns it own `el` and the caller puts that `el` in a container somewhere on the page.

Comment: Mu, is there any way I could send you my project as a .zip? this problem is totally confounding.

Comment: I can demonstrate a simple 2 line change, A works, B doesn't, but A is not the right way to do it. B is the righter way, but somehow doesn't work.

Comment: Can't you strip it down and set it up on jsfiddle.net?